# Non-bloch function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

I'm studying the Bloch space $\mathcal{B}$; this is the set of all analytic fuctions $f$ defined on the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ such that $$\sup_{|z|<1}(1-|z|^2)|f'(z)|<\infty$$

can you give me an example of a non-bloch function, i.e a function such that $$\sup_{|z|<1}(1-|z|^2)|f'(z)|=\infty$$

Comment: $> \infty$? That's going to be difficult :)

Comment: take $\frac{1}{1-z}$ though $\sup_{|z|<1}(1-|z|^2)|f'(z)|=\infty$ as @Martin pointed out